# Can i use svnsync to synchronize between two folders in the same repository?

Tags: svn, svnsync

Can I use svnsync in order to synchronize two folders in the same repository?
I have 6 subfolders (projects) in my repository. Each project contains a set of books (in the books subfolder). But, I want to create another folder in the root folder where I can mirror all files in each books subfolders.

Ex:
-root
----  project_1
--------     books
------------        file1
------------        file2
----  project_2
--------     books
------------        file3
----  index (mirror)
-------    file1 (mirror of project_1/books)
-------    file2 (mirror of project_1/books)
-------    file3 (mirror of project_2/books)

Comment: Externals would probably accomplish what you want more easily.

Comment: Thanks. Im new svn user, so, can you help me with the syntax?

Answer (score 0):

No. svnsync perform only full mirror of one repo into another

you must to use svn:externals, as @AndrewMedico already noted

For **physical directory** `/index` (you can't get aggregated single folder from different) linked files in it are result of such externals (`svn help ps`)

```
svn pg svn:externals file:///Z:/Repo/index
^/project_1/books/file1 file1
^/project_1/books/file2 file2
^/project_2/books/file3 file3
```

Comment: Thanks. Im new svn user, so, can you help me with the syntax?

Comment: @Ewelton - read [SVNBook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.externals.html)